# core-1.8.0 AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android

My config setting:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
   dependencies {
       implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.2.4"
       implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
       implementation "androidx.core:core:1.8.0"
       ...
   }
...
}
```

The error message

```
/Users/project_xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/253e1f848d23fb0aa7dda4fdaafb503b/core-1.8.0/res/values/values.xml:104:5-113:25: AAPT: error: resource
```

It started by androidx.core:core:1.7.0
Then I have tried to update like : androidx.core:core:**1.8.0**, androidx.core:core:**1.9.0**
still get the same errors.

BTW, I've tried clean, rebuild even Invalidate caches and Restart. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed all error messages by
upgrading for 1)compileSdkVersion 2)gradle 3)AS

1)compileSdkVersion

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23        
        targetSdkVersion 33
        multiDexEnabled true
...
    }
...
}
```

2)gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

    }
}
```

[image]

3)AS

[image]